# nvi: how to define a new command to write using sudo

Tags: save, nvi, sudo

In Vim, I can define the following command for writing a file using sudo:

```
command! W :execute ':silent w !sudo tee % > /dev/null' | :edit!
```

How do I define a similar command in nvi for saving using sudo? Is it possible?

Comment: nvi does not allow to define custom commands, if i recall correctly

Comment: Nvi allows defining custom keybindings (e.g. `map gg 1G`) but not custom commands.

Comment: that's what I said